# How to run multiple roscore/master in multiple machine?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my project is to make a ground station "laptop" communicate with multiple raspberry-pi and multiple arduino ... can I run more than one roscore to run ROS on multiple machines to avoid single point of failure .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226969/how-to-run-multiple-roscore/master-in-multiple-machine?/) by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

multimaster_fkie is the answer .
http://fkie.github.io/multimaster_fkie/

---

Originally posted by [Moon](https://answers.ros.org/users/25979/moon/) with karma: 19 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0